# AWS EKS: Service(LoadBalancer) running but not responding to requests

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks, kubernetes-service

I am using AWS EKS.
I have launched my django app with help of gunicorn in kubernetes cluster.

```
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: api
  labels:
    app: api
    type: web
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: api
        type: web
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: vogofleet
        image: xx.xx.com/api:image2
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        env:
        - name: DATABASE_HOST
          value: "test-db-2.xx.xx.xx.xx.com"
        - name: DATABASE_PASSWORD
          value: "xxxyyyxxx"
        - name: DATABASE_USER
          value: "admin"
        - name: DATABASE_PORT
          value: "5432"
        - name: DATABASE_NAME
          value: "test"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9000
```

I have applied these changes and I can see my pod running in `kubectl get pods`

Now, I am trying to expose it via service object. Here is my service object,

```
# service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: api
  labels:
    app: api
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 9000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: 9000
  selector:
    app: api
    type: web
  type: LoadBalancer
```

The service is also up and running. It has given me the external IP to access the service, which is the address of the load balancer. I can see that it has launched a new load balancer in the AWS console. But I am not able to access it from browser. It says that address didn't return any data. The ELB is showing the healthcheck on instances as OutOfService.

There are other pods also running in the cluster. When I run `printenv` in those pods, here is the result,

```
root@consumer-9444cf7cd-4dr5z:/consumer# printenv | grep API
API_PORT_9000_TCP_ADDR=172.20.140.213
API_SERVICE_HOST=172.20.140.213
API_PORT_9000_TCP_PORT=9000
API_PORT=tcp://172.20.140.213:9000
API_PORT_9000_TCP=tcp://172.20.140.213:9000
API_PORT_9000_TCP_PROTO=tcp
API_SERVICE_PORT=9000
```

And I tried to check connection to my api pod,

```
root@consumer-9444cf7cd-4dr5z:/consumer# telnet $API_PORT_9000_TCP_ADDR $API_PORT_9000_TCP_PORT
Trying 172.20.140.213...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

But, when I do port-forward to my localhost, I can access it on my localhost,

```
$ kubectl port-forward api-6d94dcb65d-br6px 9000
```

and check the connection,

```
$ nc -vz localhost 9000
found 0 associations
found 1 connections:
     1: flags=82<CONNECTED,PREFERRED>
  outif lo0
  src ::1 port 53299
  dst ::1 port 9000
  rank info not available
  TCP aux info available

Connection to localhost port 9000 [tcp/cslistener] succeeded!
```

Why am I not able to access it from other containers and from public internet? And, *The security groups are correct*.

Comment: Can you maybe post the output of
`kubectl describe service api`?

Comment: Did you find the problem? How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. Here's the o/p of kubectl describe service command.

`kubectl describe services nginx-elb
Name:                     nginx-elb
Namespace:                default
Labels:                   deploy=slido
Annotations:              service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: true
Selector:                 deploy=slido
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       10.100.29.66
LoadBalancer Ingress:     internal-a2d259057e6f94965bfc1f08cf86d4ce-884461987.us-west-2.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:                     http  80/TCP
TargetPort:               3000/TCP
NodePort:                 http  32582/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.60.119:3000
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:
  Type    Reason                Age   From                Message
  ----    ------                ----  ----                -------
  Normal  EnsuringLoadBalancer  119s  service-controller  Ensuring load balancer
  Normal  EnsuredLoadBalancer   117s  service-controller  Ensured load balancer`

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. I used my sample docker image.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: java17-deployment
  labels:
    app: java17-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: java17-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: java17-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: java17-app
        image: prakash/simplejava17web
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
----
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-service 
spec:
  selector:
    app: java17-app
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 8080
  type: LoadBalancer
```